# Flask API calling local method

Tags: python, flask, prolog, swi-prolog

im currently creating an API that will get some input and return a list of dictionaries in json format, the issue im having is when i want to call my methods, i get an error sometimes from CORS but its mainly cause it seems that it cant find my methods from where im calling them, heres an example:

```
from flask import Flask
import sqlite3
from pyswip import Prolog

def prologQuery():
    prolog = Prolog()
    prolog.consult("bdlogica.pl")
    g = prolog.query("propiedad(X,habitat(aquatico))")
    Lis = list(g)
    return Lis

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})


class Animales(Resource):
    def get(self):
        result = prologQuery()
        return result 
api.add_resource(Animales, "/api/get-json")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

currently with the code above it cant find prologQuery(), the method works as desired, because when I call it like this i get the result i want

```
from flask import Flask
import sqlite3
from pyswip import Prolog

def prologQuery():
    prolog = Prolog()
    prolog.consult("bdlogica.pl")
    g = prolog.query("propiedad(X,habitat(aquatico))")
    Lis = list(g)
    return Lis

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
cors = CORS(app, resources={r"/api/*": {"origins": "*"}})


class Animales(Resource):
    def get(self):
        result = prologQuery()
        return result 
api.add_resource(Animales, "/api/get-json")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

but cant seem to reach that function, the error in flask itself is:

> prologQuery() has not been defined

the error in the front-end :

> GEThttp://127.0.0.1:5000/api/get-json [HTTP/1.0 500 INTERNAL SERVER
> ERROR 80ms]
>
> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
> the remote resource at http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/get-json. (Reason:
> CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).
>
> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch
> resource.

Comment: do you get an error message and/or exception traceback ? if so, please post it, that's the best way to investigate the issue.

Comment: just did, thank you for the sugestion!

Comment: I don't see a single difference between the two codes you posted. And there is no reason you get this message with this code.

Comment: I agree with you, but the problem seems to be with the prolog library itself, ive seen some other threads but they never found a fix for this